# creating file in scala code is not usable unless terminating the code

Tags: scala, mallet

I have a Scala code in which i am creating a new file in resource directory.

And then doing some work around with that new file. (in my case splitting the file)

```
logger.debug("Run training process...")
InferTopics.main(("--input " + tmpDir + "new_corpus.mallet --inferencer " + tmpDir + "inferencer " + "--output-doc-topics " + tmpDir + "doc-topics-new.txt --num-iterations 1000").split(" "))
logger.debug("Inferring process finished.")
```

In the below code of line I am trying to split the new file created above however file is not available unless I am terminating the code.

```
val lines = Source
       .fromResource("doc-topics-new.txt")
       .getLines
       .toList
       .drop(1) match {
       case Nil => List.empty
       case x :: xs => x.split(" ").drop(2).mkString(" ") :: xs
     }
```

In a gist, The problem is File is only getting created once i am terminating the code and not after the call of 
code to create the file.

**Please note:**
The new file is getting generated by calling a mallet module, which infer an input file and create a new one 'doc-topics-new.txt'.

Any suggestion

Comment: Can you show code, where you are creating file?

Comment: I am calling an external API (mallet) to create the file. which is "InferTopics.main(("--input " + tmpDir + "new_corpus.mallet --inferencer " + tmpDir + "inferencer " + "--output-doc-topics " + tmpDir + "doc-topics-new.txt --num-iterations 1000").split(" "))". The same call in java code creates the output file however when i am trying to do the same in scala the file is not getting generated unless i am terminating the code.

Comment: So you need to kill mallet process in order for the file to be available or scala process?

Comment: could you please suggest, how can i kill that process

Comment: Ok, to sum up, if you kill your app, then file appears?

Comment: yes If i kill my app then files appear, but i believe i need to kill just the process and then in the next line the file will be used. but i am not sure how to kill a sub process in scala